# Ripple Effect When Pinching Canvas or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, hammer.js

### Explanation of My Issue

I am in the process of building a mobile application using the Cordova Framework. One of the features that my application has is a 'Pinch to Change Value' feature.

As the user pinches the screen, the number in the center of the screen will increase/decrease.

And to complicate this feature further, there is a CSS animation that needs to occur when the user pinches the screen. See the following:

[image: Ripple Pinch Example]

### My Question

Before I begin the code for this feature, I would very much appreciate some opinions on how best to achieve what I need and whether it is even possible...

For instance:

1. I will most likely be using hammer.js to capture the pinch event but is it possible to use this plugin to actually alter/set a value as opposed to just zooming in and out (I have never actually used hammer.js)?
2. When writing the code for the ripples, should I be using HTML and CSS, or would it be easier if I instead used HTML 5 Canvas? Bearing in mind that I would like to be able to link the pinching gesture to the animation... i.e. When the user pinches out, the ripples will go out from the center, when the user pinches in, the ripples go back in towards the center

Or, is there a better way to achieve this?

Essentially, in short, I am looking for advice on how best to achieve what I have outlined above...

### What I have Tried

For the ripples effect, I was able to find a snippet elsewhere that I should be able to amend to create something similar to what I need if, or course, HTML and CSS are the best method:

```css
body {
  background: #ababab;
}
.dummy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 30px;
}
.item {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2b8890;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 85px 0;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  font: 300 20px'verdana';
}
.item:hover .ring:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: ripple 1s alternate;
  animation: ripple 1s alternate;
}
.item:hover .ring:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: ripple 1s alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.20s;
  animation: ripple 1s alternate;
  animation-delay: 0.20s;
}
.item:hover .ring:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: ripple 1s alternate;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.40s;
  animation: ripple 1s alternate;
  animation-delay: 0.40s;
}
.ring {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 194px;
  width: 194px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #aba;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    left: 97px;
    top: 97px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    height: 194px;
    width: 194px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy">
  <div class="item">
    Hover Over ME
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <div class="ring"></div>
    <div class="ring"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Please note, I am not asking for the code to be written for me, I am merely asking for assistance on the underlying algorithm for best achieving what I would like to accomplish.***